# How to alias columns in Laravel Eloquent ORM using "leftJoin"

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have noticed that if we used Eloquent "LeftJoin" in query,

It is returning result set in array But, If we have same field name on both parent and relational table for example "created_date" then it will only returns field value from  relational table and overwrite value of parent table field.

How can we get value for parent table field (create_date) value as well as relational table field (create_date) value..?

Comment: Have you considered on using eager-loading? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading

Answer (score 1):

```
MainTable::leftJoin('LeftJoinTable', 'LeftJoinTable.main_id', '=', 'MainTable.id')->
selectRaw("MainTable.create_date as main_create_date, LeftJoinTable.create_date as leftJoin_create_date")->get(); //or ->first()
```

Comment: It is working but if i have field like "Fee" with float value and field type (8,2) on both parent and relational table then it will returning wrong value. for example, parent table "Fee" field has value "111.50" and relational field has "11.00", but it was returning parent field value as "110" instead of "111.50", Why..?

Comment: So, you can make another alias, mysql want exactly know what he should get.

Comment: I have already created alias for "Fee" field as below:
// QUERY USING LEFT JOIN with Eloquent
$queryObj = Appraisal::leftJoin('scope_appraisal_info', function ($join) {$join->on('scope_appraisal.appraisal_id', '=', 'scope_appraisal_info.appraisal_id');})->selectRaw('scope_appraisal.appraisal_id,scope_appraisal.appraisal_info_fee as main_fee,scope_appraisal_info.appraisal_info_fee as sub_fee')->where('scope_appraisal.appraisal_assignedto_appraisal_id', '=', $appraiserId); $result = $queryObj->get(); print_r($result);

Comment: Received response as below:
[items:protected] => Array
( [0] => V2_0\Appraisal Object
(
[table:protected] => scope_appraisal
[primaryKey:protected] => appraisal_id
[attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [appraisal_id] => 9427
                            [main_fee] => 110
                            [sub_fee] => 0
                        )

Comment: And are you sure that there is not 0? Query looks correct

Comment: i have not any issue with sub_fee => 0 which is correct, but i have issue with main_fee => 110 which has been fetched from parent table and according to database it is "111.50", so why it is showing me value "110" like integer value instead of correct float value in database.